# Tokenize a string in Oracle preserving literals

Tags: regex, oracle

I am starting with data like this:

- John went "to the store"

I'd like to tokenize this into

- John
- went
- to the store

I am trying to use the REGEXP_SUBSTR method to do this, but can't seem to come up with a regular expression that says 'match non-spaces that are not between double-quotes'

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR ('John went "to the store"', '[^[:space:]]+', 1, level) AS word
FROM
    dual
    CONNECT BY level <= LENGTH(regexp_replace('John went "to the store"','[^[:space:]]+'))
    +1
ORDER BY word ASC;
```

My brain is a little regexp fried at this point.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your delimiter a single space or could it be multiple spaces between words?  In other words if 2 spaces are encountered, is that really a NULL list element between them?

Comment: Could there be more than one double-quoted string in the main string?  Please add to your original post a sample of actual strings you have to deal with.

Comment: Two spaces should be treated as one.  And yes, there could be more than one double quoted string within the data.  This is to parse a search string.

Comment: @AlexPoole - That is very close to what I was looking for.  I used the top solution with regexp_count in the connect by to remove the NULL rows, and then added a TRIM to get rid of the double quotes.  If you answer I will accept.

Comment: @Aaron - if it is that similar then the question is a duplicate *8-)

Comment: Well just in case anyone else needs the answer that worked for me - `SELECT DISTINCT
        TRIM('"'
      FROM
        REGEXP_SUBSTR (v_words, '("[^"]*"|[^[:space:]]+)', 1, level)) AS word
      FROM
        dual
        CONNECT BY level <= regexp_count(v_words,'("[^"]*"|[^[:space:]]+)')`